# Tree widget items click listeners in Vaadin

Tags: tree, widget, vaadin, listeners

As i want to click the particular tree widget items and have to show the icon and description regarding the item in next panel tab.Please anyone have done let me know or any sample application is highly appreciated..

```
public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
  if (event.getSource() == t) {
      Object itemId = event.getItemId();
      if (event.getItem() != null) {
        Item clicked = event.getItem();
        showWindowtab();                          
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

Thanks in advance
-- Kiran kumar

Comment: What is the actual question here? This is very basic use case, and for sample code take a look at the Vaadin Sampler: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Vaadin 7 , and you defined listeners for each item, in your own code:

```
public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
  if (event.getSource() == t) {
      Object itemId = event.getItemId();
      if (event.getItem() != null) {
        Item clicked = event.getItem();
        showWindowtab(clicked.getItemId());                          
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Your showWindowTab() method should open a Window (maybe modal?), and show the information you need, like:

```
public void showWindowTab(int itemId){ 

    Window w = new Window("Item description");
    VerticalLayout v = new VerticalLayout();
    Label description = new Label("This is the item description.");

    v.addComponent(description);
    w.setContent(v);
    w.setModal(true);

    getUI().addWindow(w); 

}
```

This will add a modal window with the description, and you must get the description of the item based in the itemId parameter. If you want to use an image, you could use a Embedded and ThemeResource.